# How to disable lighttpd access log?

Tags: linux, lighttpd

I'm using lighttpd and access.log is increasing too fast.

Is there a good way to disable access log?

At the lighttpd.conf seems that is possible to disable "mod_accesslog" in the "server.modules", but the comment advices to don't do.

lighttpd 1.4.35

Answer (score 2):

You can disable `lighttpd` logging by commenting the lines as shown in bellow:

```
#"mod_accesslog"

#accesslog.filename          = "/var/log/lighttpd/access_log"
```

However, it is not a good idea. Instead, you should configure log rotation and backup.

Comment: Thanks Thiago, In my case I will ignore the access log. Do I need an external tool to manage log rotation or lighttpd.conf provide this?